# .NET Maui Create a ControlTemplate Programmatically

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui, maui-community-toolkit

I hope you can help me since I can't find much information about it, I need to redefine the appearance of the radioButtons, for which I already have the XAML controlTemplate and it works fine. But I need to create a contentView by code (CS) I can't find the way to pass the XAML to c#

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="RadioButtonTemplate">
            <Border Stroke="#F3F2F1"
                    StrokeThickness="0"
                    StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 10"
                    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                    HorizontalOptions="Start"
                    VerticalOptions="Start">
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroupList>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckedStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke"
                                            Value="#FF3300" />
                                    <Setter TargetName="check"
                                            Property="Opacity"
                                            Value="1" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor"
                                            Value="Transparent" />
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke"
                                            Value="#F3F2F1" />
                                    <Setter TargetName="check"
                                            Property="Opacity"
                                            Value="0" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateGroupList>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <Grid Margin="5">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,4,0"
                              WidthRequest="18"
                              HeightRequest="18"
                              HorizontalOptions="End"
                              VerticalOptions="Start">
                        <Ellipse Stroke="#63BBCD"
                                     Fill="White"
                                     WidthRequest="16"
                                     HeightRequest="16"
                                     HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                     VerticalOptions="Center" />
                        <Ellipse x:Name="check"
                                     Fill="#63BBCD"
                                     WidthRequest="16"
                                     HeightRequest="16"
                                     HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                     VerticalOptions="Center" />
                    </Grid>
                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" />

                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
        <Style TargetType="RadioButton">
            <Setter Property="ControlTemplate"
                    Value="{StaticResource RadioButtonTemplate}" />
        </Style>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you asking how to assign control template from resources in code behind. Or how to create control template programmatically? Because those are two completely different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually easier than you might think

You would first need to get the Resource as an object then cast it as ControlTemplate then assign it to the ContentView of choice.

```
  // if your resource is local 
  var rbTemplate = (ControlTemplate)this.Resources["RadioButtonTemplate"];
  //if your resource is global 
  var rbTemplate = (ControlTemplate)Application.Current.Resources["RadioButtonTemplate"];
  contentView.ControlTemplate = rbTemplate;
```